# Why is a degenerate quadric well defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, quadrics

Let $K$ be a field with $\text{char}(K) \neq 2$ and $Q$ be a quadric in the projective space $P(K^n)$. Let $M$ be a symmetric $n×n$-matrix over $K$ such that $Q \leftrightarrow x^T M x$.

In my course notes we defined that $Q$ is degenerate if $\text{det}(M) = 0$. Now my question is why this is well defined.

In other words, let $M'$ be another symmetric $n×n$-matrix over $K$ such that $Q \leftrightarrow x^T M' x$. Then why is it impossible that $\text{det}(M) = 0$ and $\text{det}(M') \neq 0$?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Think about a way to relate $M$ and $M'$ using a change of basis.

Comment: Do you mean to find an invertible matrix $P$ with $M = P^T M' P$ or $M = P^{-1} M P? And how can you find such a matrix?

Comment: @QuaereVerum? Please help me.

Comment: Is $M'$ a different matrix describing the same quadratic $Q$? In that case, the two matrices only differ in a scalar factor. How to show that probably depends on how you define a quadric in the first place. Once you have that, showing the determinant relationship should be easy.

Comment: @MvG yes both matrices describe the same quadric Q. That means that $[x] \in Q \iff x^T M x = 0$ and the same for $M'$. So what it basically comes down to is that we know $x^T M x = 0 \iff x^T M' x = 0$ for all $x \in K^n$. Also note that if Q is empty, the matrices dont need to be linearly dependant, for example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , the equations $x^2 +  y^2 = 0$ and $x^2 + 2y^2 = 0$ both only have zero as a solution, and thus both give the empty conic in $P(\mathbb{R}^2)$. But maybe if the quadric is not empty, they are linearly dependant (I have seen this before)? But how can you prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the following: $\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\stackrel{#1}{\Rightarrow}}$ 
i. $x^\top M x = 0$ and $x^\top M' x = 0$ have the same solution set 
ii. $det(M)=0$

Then we can choose a nonzero element $a\in ker(M)$ and prove that $a\in Ker(M')$ as well, as shown below. It follows that $det(M') = 0$.

**Lemma:** $\forall x\in K^n: a^\top M' x = 0$

Suppose that there exists an $x\in K^n$ such that $a^\top M' x \neq 0$. Then choose $\lambda=-\frac{x^\top M' x}{2a^\top M'x}$. 
Using the facts $a^\top Ma=0 \ra{} a^\top M'a=0$ and $a^\top M'x = x^\top M'a$, we can prove that the equivalence class of $x+\lambda a$ is on the quadric Q:

$$
\begin{align}
(x+\lambda a)^\top M' (x+\lambda a)
&= x^\top M'x + \lambda\cdot\left[ a^\top M'x + x^\top M'a \right] + \lambda^2 \cdot a^\top M'a \\
&= x^\top M'x + 2\lambda\cdot a^\top M'x \\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

From $(i)$ follows that $(x+\lambda a)^\top M (x+\lambda a) = 0$ as well. Because $a\in ker(M)$, it follows that
$x^\top Mx=0 \wedge (x+a)^\top M(x+a)=0$, so $x^\top M'x=0 \wedge (x+a)^\top M'(x+a)=0$. 
Subtracting both equations gives
$$
\begin{align}
0
&= x^\top M' a + a^\top M' x + a^\top M' a \\
&= 2a^\top M' x
\end{align}
$$
From which follows that $a^\top M' x = 0$, as $char(K)\neq2$. This is a contradiction, so clearly the lemma must hold.

**Conclusion:** $det(M')=0$

The lemma is equivalent to $\forall x\in K^n: x^\top(M' a) = 0$. Clearly this implies
$$
M'a=\vec{0} \ra{} a\in ker(M') \ra{} det(M')=0
$$

**Note:**
This is a very ad hoc proof. It would provide greater insight to study which symmetric matrices describe the same quadric, but that deserves its own question. The intuitive statement "M and M' describe the same quadric iff M and M' differ by a scalar factor" is wrong (shown by OP in the comments), but perhaps a modified statement could work.

Comment: You are a true hero!